# first column outside of kable table with kable_styling()

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

Why does the first column appear outside of the table in html tags when using `kable_styling()` in this pipe?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r results='asis'}
  x <- data.frame(v1=c("1", "2"),
                  v2=c("3", "4"))
  library(knitr)
  library(kableExtra)

  x %>%
    kable("html") %>%
    kable_styling()
```
````

[image]

Comment: hmm, somehow I can't reproduce this bug... https://imgur.com/a/cVIX8

Comment: I also can not reproduce your bug ...

Comment: I have exactly the same bug! Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug was caused by an incorrect handling of HTML tags on some machines [(sadly we didn't find the exact reason)](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/110) and has now been addressed in the development version of kableExtra. If anyone encounters this issue, please update your kableExtra to the latest CRAN/github version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the current version of package *"scales"* and install *"kableExtra"* again.

In my case in helped, have a look at the first screen: R was not able to remove the old version of *"scales"* package.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but no luck for me.